# inserting a background image from a changed folder into a css file

Tags: html, css, background-image

my required image filepath is xampp1/htdocs/projecto/images/bgs.jpg
my css filepath is xampp1/htdocs/projecto/css/sp.css
my css code is:

```css
body
{ margin-top:100px;
  background-color:linen;
  background-image:url("/projecto/images/bgs.jpg");
  height: 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

this is how i have linked it in my html file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/projecto/css/sp.css">
```

but my background image does not show up...

Answer (score 1):

Try to go up one level from the css folder with ../ instead of referencing directly to the project folder. Try the code below and see if it helps

```
background-image:url("../images/bgs.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

To link up an image from another folder outside of your project then it needs to be back from your project folder.For that, there use two dots that means you can access the file outside of your project.And then you show the directory of your folder.Example of your project are

```
background-image:url("../images/bgs.jpg");
```

Thank you.